# Android: Saving views that have been added programmatically

Tags: android, android-view

As my app runs, TextViews, Buttons and TableRows are added programmatically through user inputs. How can I save these views that have been added, so that they'll be there when the user reopens the app?

An example of an added button:

```
public void submitPublicQuestion(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder question = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    question.setTitle("Submit Question");
    question.setMessage("Enter question: ");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    final View queue = this.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main_class);
    final Button newBtn = new Button(this);
    newBtn.setId((int) (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF));
    question.setView(input);

    question.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();

            newBtn.setText(value);
            newBtn.setMinWidth(550);
            newBtn.setTextSize(24);
            newBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CSQuestionsLayout);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            newBtn.setLayoutParams(lp);

            ll.addView(newBtn);
        }
    });

    question.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });

    question.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't save the *actual* `View` objects over long periods, as they're not [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) or [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in any meaningful way.

What I would do instead is save off the *directions* for recreating the views. Each time you create a view based on a user's input, record what type of view was created, and any parameters associated with it (text, color, position, etc). When the app is opened, check the current state of the app against the directions list, and recreate the Views as necessary.